# Construction Brownian motion with Kolmogorov extension : prove the consistency :

Tags: probability

To prove consistency, we have to prove that $$\nu_{t_1,...,t_n}(F_{1}\times ...\times F_{n})=\nu_{t_{\pi(1)},...,t_{\pi(n)}}(F_{\pi(1)}\times ...\times F_{\pi(n)}),$$
where $\pi\in \mathfrak S(\{1,...,n\})$ a permutation.

Let define $$\nu_{t_1,...,t_n}(F_1\times ...\times F_n)=\int_{F_1}...\int_{F_n}p(t_1,0,x_1)p(t_2-t_1,x_1,x_2)...p(t_n-t_{n-1},x_{n-1},x_n)dx_1...dx_n,$$
whenever $0\leq t_1<...<t_n<\infty $ and where $$p(t,x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2t}}.$$

How can I show that this is consistent ? (it's enough to prove that $\nu_{t_1,t_2}(F_1\times F_2)\times \nu_{t_2,t_1}(F_2\times F_1)$).

Every book I'm reading say that consistency is obvious, but I really have no idea how to prove it, especially that I don't know what is $\nu_{t_2,t_1}(F_2\times F_1)$ whenever $t_2>t_1$. Can someone provide some ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure to understand your question. Anyway, with information you gave, you can't conclude. If you want to construct Brownian motion using Kolmogorov extension theorem, do as follow : Let $t_1<...<t_n$ and define
$$\nu_{t_1,...,t_n}(F_1\times ...\times F_n)=\int\limits_{F_1\times ...\times F_n} p(t_1,0,x_1)...p(t_n-t_{n-1},x_{n-1},x_n)\,\mathrm d x_1...\,\mathrm d x_n.$$

Then, for all $\pi\in \mathfrak S_n$, you define $$\nu_{t_{\pi(1)},...,t_{\pi(n)}}(F_1,...,F_n):=\nu_{t_1,...,t_n}(F_{\pi^{-1}(1)}\times ...\times F_{\pi^{-1}(n)}),$$

then then family $\{\nu_{t_{\pi(1)},...,t_{\pi(n)}}\}_{\pi\in \mathfrak S_n}$ define a family of consistent measure.

Do this for all vector of time, and the claim follow as far as you check other hypothesis of Kolmogorov extension theorem.